# Link sharing shows javascript codes with my wordpress website's name

Tags: wordpress

[image: akiveb.com script in code]

My site's name is akiveb and i am a designer. Whenever i try to share my sites link on social networking or whattsapp. A wierd javascript code shows alongside
I tried searching for a solution and till now all I can manage is that it can be a malicious attack

Thank you to whoever choses to help

Comment: I don't see anything strange on my desktop, all sharing links seems to work OK. Can you make a screenshot of what you see ?

Comment: @Angel Deykov thank you for stopping... I cannot post picture as It says that you need 10 reputation. I have shared the image link instead. Hope this helps

Comment: I really can't see this error, just shared your page on Facebook (both Home and A Poem: Your Every Bit) and all looks good, don't see this error

Comment: also I don't see any js errors on the page ...